# pointInside: withEvent:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i tried to do something like this.

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if ([self pointInside:point withEvent:event]) {
        return _scrollView;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

but i get an error like

***error: Automatic Reference Counting Issue: Receiver type 'ViewController' for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'pointInside:withEvent:'***
please help me,thanks

Answer (score 4):

What are you trying to do with that code?

`self` is a `UIViewController`, but the [`pointInside:withEvent:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW2) method is defined for `UIView`s. Try changing it to:

```
if([self.view pointInside:point withEvent:event])
```

Based on the reference to `_scrollView` though, it looks like you should be writing something like:

```
if([self.scrollView pointInside:point withEvent:event])
```

Since you return the scrollview if that test passes.

To go even one step further, though, the default behaviour for [`hitTest:withEvent:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-BBCCAICB) should in fact return `_scrollView` if it's a subview of `self.view`. So you shouldn't even need to write that method unless you're specifically excluding some of the other subviews from touch events. In that case, use the `self.scrollView` way.

Comment: i want to make a half size paging for a scrollview, which is like http://www.inediblesoftware.com/blog/2009/04/05/uiscrollview-paging-hack/ but what i can search over the net is XIB,while i m using storyboard.

Comment: Storyboarding is still very new, so there'll only be a few people who have written storyboard tutorials. That paging hack sounds like you want a [carousel](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/icarousel) which is designed for storyboards. Unfortunately, I don't know storyboards so I can't advise you further on it.

Comment: i learned to use storyboard start from my first lesson so i got limited idea on any previous solutions.anyone please help me in this.